# Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I have been using [this seed project](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter) to as the basis for my new Angular 2 project. Unfortunately, it does not come configured to use scss, so I have to add that configuration myself.

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) so am importing a default theme in my app component like this:

```
@Component( {
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [require('./app.component.css'), require('./material2-app-theme.scss')],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
} )
```

However, this yields the following error in the browser at runtime:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
```

I have tried various configurations in my webpack config, and am currently going with this:

```
{ 
    test: /\.css$/, 
    loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] 
},
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    include: [helpers.root( 'src', 'styles' )]
}
```

There are a handful of references to this error on the interweb but none of them solve my problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are only passing the `css` files, and not the `scss` files, to `to-string-loader`, so *require('./material2-app-theme.scss')* is not returning a string

Change the `scss` loader to...

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    include: [helpers.root( 'src', 'styles' )]
}
```

Also make sure that `./material2-app-theme.scss` is in the `include` folder

---

**FYI** You could easily combine these two loaders into one and simply use...

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

Comment: Yes, your second suggestion worked very well. Thanks! The first gave rise to the same error.

Comment: In the case of the first one, `material2-app-theme.scss` is probably not in the include path. You could just remove that `include` line altogether. The second is nicer anyway though

Comment: I am using angular-cli project, where is the location of scss loader in the project? I searched for that text and I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 16):

For completing the issue, if you use `ExtractTextPlugin`, the "webpack.config.js" is:

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'scss-loader?sourceMap']
    })
}
```

Then I solve issue with:

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    loaders: ['to-string-loader'].concat(ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'scss-loader?sourceMap']
    }))
}
```

Comment: I've struggling with this for days now, and this solution worked. Thanks a ton, @riofly

Comment: This has helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, add one inline loader to loaders array, with no extra installation needed

```
loaders: ['exports-loader?module.exports.toString()', other-loader]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration that works for me to load .css files.

packages.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    .....
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11"
}
```

webpack.js:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        .....
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader"]
        }
    ]
}
```

App.component:

```
@Component({
    .....
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the raw-loader from webpack which is causing this error

If you were using raw-loader get rid of that and use to-string-load

so install it

```
npm i to-string-loader --save-dev
or
yarn add to-string-loader
```

Here is my config section

```
rules: [
 {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.scss$/],
        use: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
]
```